# WebAPI Attribute Routing Not Picking Up Routes

Tags: webapi

Sitecore 8.2 rev 160729

My understanding is that, as of Sitecore 8.2, you no longer need to call `.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` [because it's now included](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/1399/4) (in fact, it'll throw an error if you do). However, Sitecore is not picking up my ApiControllers using attribute based routing.

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
    [Route("-/api/sample/test"), HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

The above route does not appear in the route tables, and the URL gives me a 404.

Do I need to tell Sitecore which assemblies to look for routes in, or is there an additional configuration step I'm missing?

Comment: I deleted my solution because your OP explicitly mentioned 8.2 and if you're getting the same result with and without the dash then the solution I posted was likely for an 8.0.x specific bug.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that your action is set to return a `string` instead of a `ContentResult`. Unless there is something special in Sitecore that allows controller actions to have a value type as the return type of an action, then this may be your culprit. I would expect that you would see "No action method found" errors, however, so I don't think this is your only issue

Comment: This is a Web API controller, not an MVC controller, so I think I'm fine returning a `string`. I believe `ContentResult` is only a thing for MVC Controllers.

Comment: You're 100% correct. End of the day for me - I must be losing it.

Comment: I installed fresh Sc 8.2.160729 via SIM (using default settings), created a simple class library with the SampleController, copied it to the website\bin and successfully received the "Hello world!" response. Are there any customizations on your side or any errors in logs?

Comment: @SergeyShushlyapin I really appreciate that. I didn't see anything in the logs, but I'm starting to suspect it may be a problem with one of our other modules

Comment: What DI are you using? Did u create a custom configurator to register your controllers in specific assemblies?

Comment: @sc.kp using the out of the box Sitecore DI. It's helix-based architecture and each project has its own configurator. The controller is registered with the DI container

Comment: may be look at https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/mvc/use_mvc_routing

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but since the sitecore `initialize`pipeline is registering the routes, is it doing it within the `/api/sitecore` prefix (like it does for mvc controllers)?  Worst case, you might be able to mock up/add your own `<initialize>` processor and debug what routes are and aren't getting registered.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem? we seem to face a similar issue. works fine in a vanilla install.

Comment: @schwindelig It's been a while and I can't remember exactly, but I don't believe I did. I think I went the route of just using an MVC controller

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by rebooting and clearing the IIS cache...

Answer (score 2):

I think since you have a DI configured that will be resetting any routes registered after you've added them so you need to do this afterwards in the initialize Pipeline like so:

**Create a pipeline to register your route:**

```
public class RegisterMySampleRoute
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("my_sample_route", 
            "mysample/api/{controller}/{action}", 
            new {controller = "SampleController"}
        );
    }
}
```

**Then patch it in like so:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="MyNamespace.Pipelines.RegisterMySampleRoute, MyNamespace" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

That should do it.

Comment: I follow the same process but the new route never matched and i always get invalid url error whenever i try hitting this url from browser.

Comment: This is for MVC routing, not WebAPI routing as the question specifies